# Python: Rendering a chart from multidimensional data

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a script to render pie charts from multidimensional array data, and am struggling trying to keep each step synchronized.

Here's my code, with some dummy data (animal types) for example:

```
def parse_data(chart):
    print("\n=====Chart Data=====")
    for a, b in chart.items(): # the dictionary "chart" has items - key:a value:b
        output = [] # list of what to print to the console
        output.append(str(a)) # key:a - the name of the superset
        if type(b) is float: # if there are no subsets and the value is a float...
            output.append(': ' + str(b) + '%') # add that number (%) to the console output list
        elif type(b) is list: # else if there are subsets they'll be in a list
            for c in b:
                for d, e in c.items():
                    output.append('\n  ' + str(d) + ': ' + str(e) + '%')
        else: # if 'b' is neither a float nor a list
            print('Error: Data could not be parsed correctly.')
        print('\n' + ''.join(map(str, output))) # put the output list together and print it

chart_data = {
    "Mammal Group": [{"Hamster":23.1}, {"Yeti":16.4}],
    "Platypus": 14.2,
    "Reptile Group": [{"Snake":4.0}, {"Komodo Dragon":0.7}]
}

parse_data(chart_data)
```

The console output is:

```
=====Chart Data=====

Mammal Group
  Hamster: 23.1%
  Yeti: 16.4%

Platypus: 14.2%

Reptile Group
  Snake: 4.0%
  Komodo Dragon: 0.7%
```

This all looks fine so far. Groups/supersets are represented by inner slices, and subsets are represented by outer slices. Notice some animals (Platypus) do not belong to a group, and a percentage is listed next to their name directly. Other animals are subsets of some larger group/superset. The next step is to grab that data and group-by-group send the data to a function to be rendered.

Here's a mock-up animating the order I imagine it would be logical to render in: Superset, then subsets of that superset, then move to the next superset if there is one. If there's no parent superset (Platypus), skip rendering of the superset and let the subset take up both inner and outer areas). The final chart will not be animated; this is only to demonstrate the order.

[image: Python chart rendering mock-up animation]

When each slice is created, the starting angle and ending angle need to be kept track of. And those angles will be different for subset slices than for superset slices. This needs to be tracked in a way so that after a set is rendered, the angle marker is placed at the end of it, ready to make the next slice.

I've got the rendering function working, but trying to feed it correct data slice by slice is driving me nuts. How can the `chart_data` be extracted in an organized way, to feed to the rendering function? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's unlikely that others will need to code something quite like this, since I have reached a solution and I would prefer not to leave this question unanswered, I will attempt to explain my solution. Anyone randomly curious can read on....

I solved this by creating two empty lists - one for the "superset" inner slices, and one for the "subset" outer slices, and then populating them as the chart data gets iterated through. Although the subset slices are always children of a superset slice in the structure of the original chart data, that structure does not need to be preserved in order to render the chart.

The supersets that have no subset children get added to both super *and* sub lists, but this is invisible in the final pie chart. To understand what is meant by "invisible", imagine that the blue slice in the mock-up image is actually comprised of an inner segment and outer segment, one beside the other. If the pie chart were uncurled and laid out as two straight parallel tracks they would still line up with one another, as they have the same percentage.

But only one should be labeled, and there is more room for text in the outer area. For this reason, superset slices containing no subset slices get their name labels removed and set to data type `None`. Those name labels get moved to each one's neighboring subset slice instead. Slices labeled `None` will not be rendered, but the place marker will rotate by the percentage of that slice. To use the mock-up image as an example, this is what allows moving from the end of the green superset slice to the beginning of the orange superset slice without drawing an unwanted second slice "over" the blue slice. (Imagine the inner superset slices as being laid on top of and covering the outer subset slices.)

As most people reading this probably know, having a data type of `None` as a key in a dictionary doesn't work more than once. for example, the entry `"Platypus" : 14.2` will result in `None : 14.2`, which will be overwritten by `"Jabberwock" : 41.6` into `None : 41.6`. Because of this, I decided to convert the dictionary `chart_data` into a list first before formatting it for the graph.

As the iteration happens, the percentages of the subset slices get tallied up so that their parent superset group matches them in size. (Size meaning *width* if laid out in two parallel tracks, and *rotation angle* if viewed in the pie chart.)

Finally, I threw in some code to check whether the chart percentages add up to 100.

```
chart_data = {
    "Mammal Group": [{"Hamster":23.1}, {"Yeti":16.4}],
    "Platypus": 14.2,
    "Reptile Group": [{"Snake":4.0}, {"Komodo Dragon":0.7}],
    "Jabberwock" : 41.6
}

track_sup = []
track_sub = []

def dict_to_list(dict): # converts a dictionary to a list (nested dictionaries are untouched)
    new_list = []
    for key, value in dict.items():
        super_pair = [key, value]
        new_list.append(super_pair)
    return new_list

def format_data(dict_data):
    global track_sup
    global track_sub
    track_sup = []
    track_sub = []
    print('\n\n\n====== Formatting data ======')
    super_slices = dict_to_list(dict_data) # convert to list to allow more than one single super slice (their labels are type: None)
    chart_perc = 0.0 # for checking that the chart slices all add up to 100%
    i = 0
    while i < len(super_slices):
        tally = 0.0 # for adding up subset percentages to get each superset percentage
        is_single = True # supersets single by default
        super_slice = super_slices[i]
        slice_label = ''
        super_pair = []
        sub_pair = []
        if type(super_slice[1]) == list: # if [1] is a list, there are sub slices
            is_single = False # mark superset as containing multiple subsets
            slice_label = super_slice[0]
            sub_slices = super_slice[1]
            j = 0
            while j < len(sub_slices): # iterate sub slices to gather label names and percentages
                sub_slice = sub_slices[j]
                for k, v in sub_slice.items(): # in each dict, k is a label and v is a percentage
                    v = float(v)
                    tally = tally + v # count toward super slice (group) percentage
                    chart_perc = chart_perc + v # count toward chart total percentage
                    sub_pair = [k, v] # convert each key-value pair into a list
                    print(str(sub_pair[0]) + ' ' + str(sub_pair[1]) + ' %')
                    track_sub.append(sub_pair) # append this pair to final sub output list
                j = j + 1
            print('Group [' + slice_label + '] combined total is ' + str(tally) + ' % \n')
        elif type(super_slice[1]) == float: # this super slice (group) contains no sub slices
            slice_label = super_slice[0]
            tally = super_slice[1] # no sub slice percentages to add up
            chart_perc = chart_perc + super_slice[1] # count toward chart total percentage
            sub_pair = [slice_label, tally] # label drops to the sub slot as it only labels itself
            track_sub.append(sub_pair) # append this pair to final sub output list
            print(slice_label + ' ' + str(tally) + ' %  (Does not belong to a group)\n')
        else:
            print('Error: Could not format data.')
        
        if is_single == True:
            slice_label = None # label removed for each single slice - only the percentage is used (for spacing)
            
        super_pair = [slice_label, tally] # pair up each label name and super slice percentage in a list
        track_sup.append(super_pair) # append this pair to final super output list
        
        i = i + 1
        
    chart_perc = round(chart_perc, 6) # round to 6 decimal places
    short = 0.0
    if chart_perc == 100.0:
        print('______ Sum of all chart slices is 100 % ______\n')
    else:
        print('****** WARNING: Chart slices do not add up to 100 % ! ******')
        short = round(100.0 - chart_perc, 6)
        print('Sum of all chart slices is only ' + str(chart_perc) + ' %  (Falling short by ' + str(short) + ' %)\n')

format_data(chart_data)
print(track_sup)
print(track_sub)
```

And the resulting console output:

```
====== Formatting data ======
Hamster 23.1 %
Yeti 16.4 %
Group [Mammal Group] combined total is 39.5 % 

Platypus 14.2 %  (Does not belong to a group)

Snake 4.0 %
Komodo Dragon 0.7 %
Group [Reptile Group] combined total is 4.7 % 

Jabberwock 41.6 %  (Does not belong to a group)

______ Sum of all chart slices is 100 % ______

[['Mammal Group', 39.5], [None, 14.2], ['Reptile Group', 4.7], [None, 41.6]]
[['Hamster', 23.1], ['Yeti', 16.4], ['Platypus', 14.2], ['Snake', 4.0], ['Komodo Dragon', 0.7], ['Jabberwock', 41.6]]
```

`track_sup` and `track_sub` are the two lists whose data is shown in the last two lines of output, that will be actually used to render the chart.